# Problems with Optimistic Concurrency for gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ado.net

In asp.net for Gridview, how to avoid optimistic concurrency ?
How the user to restrict not to edit when already the record is in edit mode ?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/implementing-optimistic-concurrency-with-the-sqldatasource-vb

Comment: Thank you.
But i am binding the data source through code, then how to set the optimistic concurrency ?

Comment: How can I able to restrict the user with out editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to check if the data changed clientside:**

I would suggest a TextBox which contains the Information and the same TextBox as "css: visibility:hidden" and readonly containing the original Information. then you can always check on clientside with JavaScript if the user changed the value of the TextBox without doing a postback to the Server.

**to lock the users edit:**

its difficult on asp to manage this cause the communication is an asyncronious way.
you can for example add a new column in your databasetable "locked"(bit) and can lock the dataset if someone enters the editmode. then you can check the locked value from some other user and restrict the edit mode for him. (care about sessions running out and so on; maybe use an timestamp as lock and open the lock after the sessionminutes expired).

**if the user is in edit mode alrdy:**

you cant lock him (if your not doing postbacks to the Server and asking him for the lock in intervals (would be done my AJAX)).
You only can check the locked value when he tries to save his changes. But this is to late cause he alrdy changed some values and they will get reverted.
Maybe you can ask him if you can see the values changed in the database if he wants to overwrite those changes.

hope this helps, noone

Comment: Thank you.. i tried in 2nd option what you have mentioned but it little difficult at the session time.

I got an idea to solve : create a static list variable and assigned to application variable, when user clicks on particular record need to store the id in list variable and after update or session end have to remove the id from the list.In order to work through in database, i thought to maintain in the application itself.
please help me is this idea going to work ?
Need your valuable thoughts ...!

Comment: I would suggest to place the list you mentioned in the database as own Standing table for example.
Cause if your application crashes you got some undefined state and cant react. For example with the session ran out you can make the lock via timestamp and check if the timestamp for the lock was 15min ago. or check in intervals if the user which locked the data is still working on it (session alive). else you can drop the lock from the database.
I would suggest to store your table in your database as ownstanding table.

Comment: Thank you..
i am clear now with your idea.. i will code with sessions